# Why does my gridview's edit\update not work after I add item to it at runtime

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

On my Page I have a textbox and a submit button which adds an item to my gridview which has edit/update functionality.All this is in an update panel.

I am binding my gridview with data from database using sqlreader. The edit/update option works fine when it bind it first time. but once I add an Item at runtime, the newly added item gets added to my gridview but edit update stops working. Also, not able to add new item after that.

Please find my sample code below

- This is my HTML code:
  -

```html
<li>
                                               <input type="radio" id="tabb" name="tabs11"/>
                                               <label for="tabb">Family Name</label>
                                               <div id="tab-content12" class="tab-content animated fadeIn" style="background-color:white; padding:10px;" >
                                                   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                                                      <ContentTemplate>
                                                          <asp:Button ID="BtnAddFamilyName" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="buttons" OnClick="BtnAddFamilyName_Click" /><br />
                                                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Family Name"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                          <asp:TextBox ID="FamilyNameTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="inputs" placeholder="Enter Family Name"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                          <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmitFamilyName" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="BtnSubmitFamilyName_Click" CssClass="inputs"/><br /><br />
                                                          <asp:GridView ID="gdvEDitFamilyName" runat="server" OnRowEditing="gdvEDitFamilyName_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gdvEDitFamilyName_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gdvEDitFamilyName_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" DataKeyNames="FamilyId" CssClass="grid" RowStyle-CssClass="rows">
                                                          </asp:GridView>
                                                      </ContentTemplate>
                                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>          
                                               </div>
                                           </li>
```

2: My code behind for binding the gridview:

```
SqlDataReader reader = DataExecuter.ReadMultipleRows("spBindHIGridview", 
              CommandType.StoredProcedure);
reader.NextResult();
gdvEDitFamilyName.DataSource = reader;
gdvEDitFamilyName.DataBind();
```

3:My code behind for adding the item to the grid:

```
protected void BtnSubmitFamilyName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FamilyNameTextBox.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, 
                this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please enter a 
                 value')", true);
            }
            else
            {

                DataExecuter.ExecuteCommand("spInsertFamilyName", new[,] { { 
                "@FamilyName", FamilyNameTextBox.Text } }, 
                CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                this.BindDdl();
                this.BindGrid();
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, 
                this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted 
                Successfully')", true);
            }
        }
```

After the 3rd step i can't add a new item or edit/update the gridview

Comment: There is nothing in HTML code. Can you update it?

Comment: What happens when you try to add or update item? Any error? Did you try to debug the code to see what is happening?

Comment: When I click the edit button on the gridview nothing happens . Same with the Submit and Add button

Comment: Did you try debugging? Is it hitting break points?

Comment: Yes , I added a break point at the row editing event . It is not hitting the break point.